# How do I create regular expression for a string to match [@username:4]?

Tags: java, php, regex

I need to create a regular expression to detect a string matching the format below for **Java and Php**:

**[@username:4]**

where **'username'** can be **any text** and **'4'** can be **any integer**. I tried creating one myself but I am new to the world of regular expressions and was unable to do so. This is the furthest I got :

**([[]+[@]+[A-Za-z0-9])\w+**

Any help will be great.Thanks!

Comment: Username can be any text at all? Including @ and : and any other punctuation? Not that you cannot write a regexp for it — you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way of doing it would be to use this regular expression:

```
\[@\w+:\d+\]
```

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/v43VJm/1)

which does what you asked for but has a disadvantage. It doesn't take the length of the username or the integer into account.

 I don't know if it is important in your case but i personally would prefer this regex:

```
\[@\w{1,25}:\d{1,5}\]
```

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/wahAye/1)

Which does exactly the same as the one above but doesn't allow for infinitely long username or number and sets the bounds for both.
In perticular, `\w{1,25}` means that it will match any word character (a-zA-Z0-9_) between 1 and 25 times (inclusive). Therefore the longest username is 25 characters long and the shortest possible is 1 character long. These values can be tweaked.
Likewise it restricts the integer length between 1 and 5 characters therefore any integer with more than 5 digits or less than 1 is invalid: `\d{1,5}` Again, the values can be tweaked.

Comment: @Ark Horray! Glad i helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

Would the username ever have :'s in it? If not use the following

```
\[@([^:]+):(\d+)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/7iqrPm/1

If the username would never have brackets then use the following:

```
\[@([^:\]]+)(?::(\w+))?\]
```

It also makes the :integer part optional

https://regex101.com/r/FmfAze/3

Comment: The `[^:]+` [might make this expression overfire](https://regex101.com/r/FmfAze/2).

Comment: Updated for your case @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1):

```
\[@\w+\:\d+\]
```

`\w` means all word can be username, it supports `a-z,A-Z,0-9 and _`

`\d` means all digital, `0-9`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It works! Accepted @fillpant's answer as it had explaination and option for limit.